# Image above form in Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a responsive webpage (using Bootstrap) containing an image above a form. Since the image is very large, it is put in a "peek-view" container which shows only a
a small part of it and has both horizontal and vertical scrolling.

In my CSS, I use two layers of containers containing my image, as follows :

```
.outer-container-for-image { 
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px; 
  overflow: auto; /* Activate scrollbars */
}

.inner-container-for-image { 
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}

.inner-container-for-image img { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

I get the following results in Google Chrome, for a mobile and desktop viewport respectively :

[image: Mobile view]
[image: Desktop view]

In the mobile output, the image is centered (almost) correctly (it is slightly nearer the right than the left), but the text field is not and the image does not have the same width as the text field.

In the desktop output, neither the image nor the text field is centered correctly (they are left-aligned) and
the image does not have the same width as the text field.

How can I fix this?

My source code :

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/*!
     * Bootstrap  v5.2.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
     * Copyright 2011-2022 The Bootstrap Authors
     * Copyright 2011-2022 Twitter, Inc.
     * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
     */

 :root {
  /* 8 */
  --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
  --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
  --bs-purple: #6f42c1;
  --bs-pink: #d63384;
  --bs-red: #dc3545;
  --bs-orange: #fd7e14;
  --bs-yellow: #ffc107;
  --bs-green: #198754;
  --bs-teal: #20c997;
  --bs-cyan: #0dcaf0;
  --bs-black: #000;
  --bs-white: #fff;
  --bs-gray: #6c757d;
  --bs-gray-dark: #343a40;
  --bs-gray-100: #f8f9fa;
  --bs-gray-200: #e9ecef;
  --bs-gray-300: #dee2e6;
  --bs-gray-400: #ced4da;
  --bs-gray-500: #adb5bd;
  --bs-gray-600: #6c757d;
  --bs-gray-700: #495057;
  --bs-gray-800: #343a40;
  --bs-gray-900: #212529;
  --bs-primary: #0d6efd;
  --bs-secondary: #6c757d;
  --bs-success: #198754;
  --bs-info: #0dcaf0;
  --bs-warning: #ffc107;
  --bs-danger: #dc3545;
  --bs-light: #f8f9fa;
  --bs-dark: #212529;
  --bs-primary-rgb: 13, 110, 253;
  --bs-secondary-rgb: 108, 117, 125;
  --bs-success-rgb: 25, 135, 84;
  --bs-info-rgb: 13, 202, 240;
  --bs-warning-rgb: 255, 193, 7;
  --bs-danger-rgb: 220, 53, 69;
  --bs-light-rgb: 248, 249, 250;
  --bs-dark-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
  --bs-white-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --bs-black-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --bs-body-color-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
  --bs-body-bg-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --bs-font-sans-serif: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  --bs-font-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  --bs-gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  --bs-body-font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif);
  --bs-body-font-size: 1rem;
  --bs-body-font-weight: 400;
  --bs-body-line-height: 1.5;
  --bs-body-color: #212529;
  --bs-body-bg: #fff;
  --bs-border-width: 1px;
  --bs-border-style: solid;
  --bs-border-color: #dee2e6;
  --bs-border-color-translucent: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  --bs-border-radius: 0.375rem;
  --bs-border-radius-sm: 0.25rem;
  --bs-border-radius-lg: 0.5rem;
  --bs-border-radius-xl: 1rem;
  --bs-border-radius-2xl: 2rem;
  --bs-border-radius-pill: 50rem;
  --bs-link-color: #0d6efd;
  --bs-link-hover-color: #0a58ca;
  --bs-code-color: #d63384;
  --bs-highlight-bg: #fff3cd;
}


/* 79*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
   :root {
    /* 84 */
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}

body {
  /* 89 */
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
  font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
  line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
  text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
  background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label {
  /* 332 */
  display: inline-block;
}

.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-xxl,
.container-xl,
.container-lg,
.container-md,
.container-sm {
  /* 627 */
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  /* 662 */
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));
  margin-right: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
  margin-left: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
}

.row>* {
  /* 671 */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}

.col-12 {
  /* 779 */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.m-4 {
  /* 7412 */
  margin: 1.5rem !important;
}

.pt-4 {
  /* 7706 */
  padding-top: 1.5rem !important;
}

 :root,
 :host {
  /* 18956 */
  --fa-style-family-brands: "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
  --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
}

 :root,
 :host {
  /* 20982 */
  --fa-style-family-classic: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}

 :root,
 :host {
  /* 21004 */
  --fa-style-family-classic: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}

.outer-container-for-image {
  /* 21026 */
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Activate scrollbars */
}

.inner-container-for-image {
  /* 21033 */
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}

.inner-container-for-image img {
  /* 21039 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.order-form .container {
  /* 21099 */
  color: #4c4c4c;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 650px;
}

.order-form-label {
  /* 21106 */
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section class="order-form m-4">
  <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="outer-container-for-image">
            <div class="inner-container-for-image">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zsLb5NY/large-beach.png" alt="Big image">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row mt-3 mx-4">
          <div class="col-12">
            <label class="order-form-label" for="text-field">Name</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-outline datepicker" data-mdb-toggle-button="false">
              <input type="text" class="form-control order-form-input" id="text-field" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
      "></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code because you had a lot of necessary elements (e.g., nested grids). Other than that, you need to add the following:

- `d-flex justify-content-center` to the `row`
- `mx-auto mw-100` to the `outer-container-for-image`

See the snippet below.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/*!
     * Bootstrap  v5.2.3 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
     * Copyright 2011-2022 The Bootstrap Authors
     * Copyright 2011-2022 Twitter, Inc.
     * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/LICENSE)
     */

:root {
  /* 8 */
  --bs-blue: #0d6efd;
  --bs-indigo: #6610f2;
  --bs-purple: #6f42c1;
  --bs-pink: #d63384;
  --bs-red: #dc3545;
  --bs-orange: #fd7e14;
  --bs-yellow: #ffc107;
  --bs-green: #198754;
  --bs-teal: #20c997;
  --bs-cyan: #0dcaf0;
  --bs-black: #000;
  --bs-white: #fff;
  --bs-gray: #6c757d;
  --bs-gray-dark: #343a40;
  --bs-gray-100: #f8f9fa;
  --bs-gray-200: #e9ecef;
  --bs-gray-300: #dee2e6;
  --bs-gray-400: #ced4da;
  --bs-gray-500: #adb5bd;
  --bs-gray-600: #6c757d;
  --bs-gray-700: #495057;
  --bs-gray-800: #343a40;
  --bs-gray-900: #212529;
  --bs-primary: #0d6efd;
  --bs-secondary: #6c757d;
  --bs-success: #198754;
  --bs-info: #0dcaf0;
  --bs-warning: #ffc107;
  --bs-danger: #dc3545;
  --bs-light: #f8f9fa;
  --bs-dark: #212529;
  --bs-primary-rgb: 13, 110, 253;
  --bs-secondary-rgb: 108, 117, 125;
  --bs-success-rgb: 25, 135, 84;
  --bs-info-rgb: 13, 202, 240;
  --bs-warning-rgb: 255, 193, 7;
  --bs-danger-rgb: 220, 53, 69;
  --bs-light-rgb: 248, 249, 250;
  --bs-dark-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
  --bs-white-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --bs-black-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  --bs-body-color-rgb: 33, 37, 41;
  --bs-body-bg-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
  --bs-font-sans-serif: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  --bs-font-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  --bs-gradient: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  --bs-body-font-family: var(--bs-font-sans-serif);
  --bs-body-font-size: 1rem;
  --bs-body-font-weight: 400;
  --bs-body-line-height: 1.5;
  --bs-body-color: #212529;
  --bs-body-bg: #fff;
  --bs-border-width: 1px;
  --bs-border-style: solid;
  --bs-border-color: #dee2e6;
  --bs-border-color-translucent: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  --bs-border-radius: 0.375rem;
  --bs-border-radius-sm: 0.25rem;
  --bs-border-radius-lg: 0.5rem;
  --bs-border-radius-xl: 1rem;
  --bs-border-radius-2xl: 2rem;
  --bs-border-radius-pill: 50rem;
  --bs-link-color: #0d6efd;
  --bs-link-hover-color: #0a58ca;
  --bs-code-color: #d63384;
  --bs-highlight-bg: #fff3cd;
}


/* 79*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
   :root {
    /* 84 */
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
}

body {
  /* 89 */
  margin: 0;
  font-family: var(--bs-body-font-family);
  font-size: var(--bs-body-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--bs-body-font-weight);
  line-height: var(--bs-body-line-height);
  color: var(--bs-body-color);
  text-align: var(--bs-body-text-align);
  background-color: var(--bs-body-bg);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label {
  /* 332 */
  display: inline-block;
}

.container,
.container-fluid,
.container-xxl,
.container-xl,
.container-lg,
.container-md,
.container-sm {
  /* 627 */
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  /* 662 */
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  --bs-gutter-y: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--bs-gutter-y));
  margin-right: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
  margin-left: calc(-0.5 * var(--bs-gutter-x));
}

.row>* {
  /* 671 */
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * 0.5);
  margin-top: var(--bs-gutter-y);
}

.col-12 {
  /* 779 */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.m-4 {
  /* 7412 */
  margin: 1.5rem !important;
}

.pt-4 {
  /* 7706 */
  padding-top: 1.5rem !important;
}

:root,
:host {
  /* 18956 */
  --fa-style-family-brands: "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
  --fa-font-brands: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Brands";
}

:root,
:host {
  /* 20982 */
  --fa-style-family-classic: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  --fa-font-solid: normal 900 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}

:root,
:host {
  /* 21004 */
  --fa-style-family-classic: "Font Awesome 6 Free";
  --fa-font-regular: normal 400 1em/1 "Font Awesome 6 Free";
}

.outer-container-for-image {
  /* 21026 */
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
  /* Activate scrollbars */
}

.inner-container-for-image {
  /* 21033 */
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}

.inner-container-for-image img {
  /* 21039 */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.order-form .container {
  /* 21099 */
  color: #4c4c4c;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-width: 650px;
}

.order-form-label {
  /* 21106 */
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="order-form m-4">
  <div class="container pt-4">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="outer-container-for-image mx-auto mw-100">
          <div class="inner-container-for-image">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/zsLb5NY/large-beach.png" alt="Big image">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 mt-3 mx-4">
        <label class="order-form-label" for="text-field">Name</label>
        <div class="form-outline datepicker" data-mdb-toggle-button="false">
          <input type="text" class="form-control order-form-input" id="text-field" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot. I'll wait and take some time to look if there's nothing missing before accepting this answer.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Is everything working?